# Why can’t homomorphic signatures be derived directly from homomorphic encryption

Tags: encryption, signature

I am reading this survey paper.

https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/0d25/419e80fff2599c47d5c86f77ebe717feb534.pdf

It's not clear to me (yet) why the Sig(), Vry() and Eval() function can't just be defined in a straightforward manner from the enc() and dec() functions of a standard homomorphic encryption scheme.

Comment: It is well written in the article. `translating functions on messages into functions on signatures` It enables existential forgeries, this is due to the homomorphic properties of the signature. As in RSA, if we don't use a secure signature scheme like RSA-PSS then one can multiply the encryption to forge another one.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't a programming question. I think this would be a fit on [crypto SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/).